# writing inner join in wpdb

Tags: mysql, wpdb, join-tables

I have a problem in writing SQL Inner Join syntax in wordpress, 
This logic should definitely work, I tried this in phpmyadmin and it works fine

```
SELECT booking_calendars.cal_name
FROM booking_calendars 
INNER JOIN booking_reservation 
ON booking_calendars.id = booking_reservations.calendar_id
WHERE status LIKE 'pending'
```

but it doesn't in wordpress

```
$pending_reservations = $wpdb->get_results(" 
    SELECT booking_calendars.cal_name
    FROM'.$wpdb->prefix.'booking_calendars AS booking_calendars
    INNER JOIN' . $wpdb->prefix.'booking_reservation AS booking_reservations
    ON booking_calendars.id =  booking_reservations.calendar_id
    WHERE status LIKE 'pending'");
```

and then

```
echo "<h2>Pending Reservation: </h2><br>";
        var_dump( $pending_reservations);
        if($pending_reservations>0)
        {
        foreach ( $pending_reservations as $pending_reservation ) 
        {
            echo "<label>". $pending_reservation->cal_name."</label><br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<label>No Pending Reservation</label><br>";
    }
```

I var_dumped `$pending_reservations` and it returns `array(0) { }` in wordpress

Comment: What about this one? `"SELECT booking_calendars.cal_name
FROM {$wpdb->booking_calendars} AS booking_calendars
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->booking_reservation} AS booking_reservations
ON booking_calendars.id = booking_reservations.calendar_id
WHERE status LIKE 'pending'"`

Comment: Have you tried to echo your query to see what is being generated? My guess is that it is trying to query against a `wp_booking_calendars` table since you are appending `$wpdb->prefix`

Comment: @czerspalace that's a good point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your time and thanks to @czerspalace 
I started the query with double quotation and then separate it with a single quotation and after looking at the echo output I found that there's no spaces between `From` and `table name`

this is the correct way

```
$pending_reservations = $wpdb->get_results(' 
    SELECT booking_calendars.cal_name
    FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'booking_calendars AS booking_calendars
    INNER JOIN '. $wpdb->prefix.'booking_reservation AS booking_reservations
    ON booking_calendars.id =  booking_reservations.calendar_id
    WHERE status LIKE "pending"');
```